# pure css slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to get one pure css slider (http://jsfiddle.net/trN4p/1/) to operate within another pure css slider on the same document/page using `:target` for navigation with independent control for each slider.

**Here is an example of the problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/J6htH/4/

**I want the inside (CHILD) slider to work independently of and alongside (w/out conflict) the outside (PARENT) slider.**

I was wondering if there is a way to separate the two sliders so that their list items (and hash tags) operate relative to the slider and not the whole page/dom? Is there some **jQuery/Ajax** magic or **JS templating (backbone/underscore)** tricks to do this?

Comment: Just want to say, your fiddle is awesome!

Comment: Thank you Johnny. It is simple replacement of JS sliders using only CSS. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say it (because I understand how awesome it feels to make really cool things in pure CSS), but you should use JavaScript.

Bear with me here, and comment if you feel i'm being unreasonable:

You can only have a single element that's matched as `:target`, because you can only have one hashtag, so at most you can have **one** slider set to a particular item at a time (the other would return to default). This is the constraint, whether you like it or not.

On the other hand, HTML+CSS+JS is a great example of the Model-View-Controller pattern/model/concept.

- HTML is the `Model` as it contains all the `data`
- CSS is the `View` as it contains all the `styles`
- JS is the `Controller` as it defines how the `user`, data and styles `interact` with each other.

You're trying to make a slider which involves user interactions. The triggering events (like `click`) should really be handled by the `Controller`, not the `View`.

**tl;dr:**

You can't do what you're describing in *pure* CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping that would not be the case. If you run the code outside of jsfiddle (in a local .html file), you would see that if you click next on the inside (red) slider and refresh the page, you would notice that now you can only control the inside (red) slider. I was wondering if there is a way to separate the two sliders so that their list items (and hash tags) operate relative to the slider and not the whole page/dom? Is there some jQuery/Ajax magic or JS templating (backbone/underscore) tricks to do this?

Comment: Thank you for a great explanations in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    .csslider1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 830px;

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_anchor {
    display: none;
}
.csslider1 > ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.csslider1 > ul > div {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0;
}
.csslider1 > ul > li.img img {
    width: 100%;
}
.csslider1 > ul > li.img {
    font-size: 0pt;
}
.csslider1 > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: initial;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.csslider1 .cs_lnk{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    font-size: 0pt;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.csslider1 > ul > li.img,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext,
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets,
.csslider1 > .cs_play_pause {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    z-index: 5;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label {
    position: absolute;

    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev {
    left: 0;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
    right: 0;
}

.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label,
.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num2,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num2,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num0,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num0,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num2,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num2,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num0,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num0 {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrow {
    0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
    33.333333333333336%, 100%   { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes arrow {
    0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
    33.333333333333336%, 100%   { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes arrow {
    0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
    33.333333333333336%, 100%   { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}


.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num2,
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num1 {
    -webkit-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
    -moz-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
    animation: arrow 12300ms infinite -1000ms;

}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num0,
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num2 {
    -webkit-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
    -moz-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
    animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 3100ms;

}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label.num0 {
    -webkit-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
    -moz-animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
    animation: arrow 12300ms infinite 7200ms;

}

.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label,
.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_arrowprev > label,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_arrownext > label {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    -o-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}

.csslider1 > .cs_bullets {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 8pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > div {
    margin-left: -50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 0;
    left: -55px;
    top: -48px;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb > img {
    max-width: none;
}
.csslider1.cs_handle {
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABwSURBVEjH7ZJBEsAgCAMT/v/n9NCOSqe2oD2yNx1JggB4BCEFWyFASP2KMQE7ywWhe/tTRGCGogLk02tFctiW/SUgaMyQG4PdPzDn31rQbMb8FiAXgvsEJNax1yVlVGAjA93apP3HFhZTGIqiKH7iADB6HxPlHdNVAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjEwKzAyOjAwm7WiFAAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxNC0wNy0wN1QxMzo0OToxMCswMjowMOroGqgAAAAASUVORK5CYII="), move;
}
.csslider1.cs_handle.cs_grab {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABaSURBVEjH7ZMxCkAhDEOT8u9/5TpJ+xWkFse8IYutJgEB8RCHL1qCc90BEFnT6QH7mwgFHBUf8wJyS1TDLuc3vmighx37LZdIth3E5hKj9n6O0HRh+oJCiFcMxRUUDxR1CTMAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTQtMDctMDdUMTM6NDk6MzgrMDI6MDDqf+sOAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjM4KzAyOjAwmyJTsgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), move;
}

.csslider1 > ul > li.num0 {
    left: 0%;
}
.csslider1 > ul > li.num1 {
    left: 100%;
}
.csslider1 > ul > li.num2 {
    left: 200%;
}

.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ ul > li,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ ul > li {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);

}
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ ul > li,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ ul > li {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);

}
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ ul > li,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ ul > li {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);

}

.csslider1 > ul > li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1000ms;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1000ms;
    transition: transform 1000ms;



    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);

}


@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%, 25.203252032520325% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187%    { -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%); }

}
@-moz-keyframes slide {
    0%, 25.203252032520325% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); }
    33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187%    { -moz-transform: translateX(-200%); }

}
@keyframes slide {
    0%, 25.203252032520325% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    33.333333333333336%, 58.53658536585366% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
    66.66666666666667%, 91.869918699187%    { transform: translateX(-200%); }

}


.csslider1  > #cs_play1:checked ~ ul > li {
    -webkit-animation: slide 12300ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: slide 12300ms infinite;
    animation: slide 12300ms infinite;

}


.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ ul > li,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ ul > li {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;

}


/* /calculate autoplay */
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 15%;
    opacity: .5;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev:hover,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext:hover {
    opacity: .9;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev {
    left: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext {
    right: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span {
    float: left;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span {
    float: right;
}

.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span:after,
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -23px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    content:'';
}

.csslider1 > .cs_arrowprev > label span:after {
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    background-size:100% auto;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_arrownext > label span:after {
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    background-size:100% auto;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets {
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label {
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}

.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    margin-top: -13px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s;

}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label > .cs_thumb:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    bottom: -10px;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;

    border-top: 7px solid #fff;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_bullets > label:hover > .cs_thumb {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_0:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num0,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_0:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num0,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num1,
.csslider1 > #cs_slide1_2:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num2,
.csslider1 > #cs_pause1_2:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num2 {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bullet {
    0%, 33.32333333333334%  {
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    33.333333333333336%, 100% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bullet {
    0%, 33.32333333333334%  {
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    33.333333333333336%, 100% {
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes bullet {
    0%, 33.32333333333334%  {
        box-shadow: none;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    33.333333333333336%, 100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num0 {
    -webkit-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
    -moz-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;
    animation: bullet 12300ms infinite -1000ms;

}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num1 {
    -webkit-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
    -moz-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;
    animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 3100ms;

}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label.num2 {
    -webkit-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
    -moz-animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;
    animation: bullet 12300ms infinite 7200ms;

}

.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;

}

.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_bullets > label > .cs_point {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    -o-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}


/* ------------- Play ------------- */
.csslider1 > .cs_play_pause{display:block;}

.csslider1 > .cs_play_pause {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
.csslider1 > .cs_play_pause > label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause,
.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play {
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play,
.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause {
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}



@-webkit-keyframes pauseChange {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
  33.333333333333336%, 100%  { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes pauseChange {
  0%, 33.32333333333334% { opacity: 1; z-index: 5; }
  33.333333333333336%, 100%  { opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}


.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause.num0 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite -1900ms;
  animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite -1900ms;
}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause{display:none;}

.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause.num1 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 1700ms;
  animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 1700ms;
}
.csslider1 > #cs_play1:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause.num2 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 5300ms;
  animation: pauseChange 10800ms infinite 5300ms;
}


.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause,
.csslider1 > .pause:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_pause {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}

/* ------------- Play Pause CSS ------------- */
.csslider1{position:relative}
.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play{
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 5;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.csslider1 > .slide:checked ~ .cs_play_pause > .cs_play:hover{ background: rgba(0,0,0,1);}
.csslider1 > .cs_play_pause {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-right: 0;
    z-index: 111;
}
<div class="csslider1 autoplay cs_handle" style="width: 300px;">
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide" />
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide" />
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_slide1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor slide" />
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_play1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor" checked="" />
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_0" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause" />
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_1" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause" />
    <input name="cs_anchor1" id="cs_pause1_2" type="radio" class="cs_anchor pause" />

    <ul>
        <div>
            <img src="https://webdevpuneet.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/cat3.png" style="width: 100%;" />
        </div>
        <li class="num0 img">
            <a href="https://webdevpuneet.com/css-only-slider/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://webdevpuneet.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/cat3.png" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="num1 img">
            <a href="https://webdevpuneet.com/css-only-slider/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://webdevpuneet.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/cat2.png" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="num2 img">
            <a href="https://webdevpuneet.com/css-only-slider/" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://webdevpuneet.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/cat1.png" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="cs_play_pause">
        <label class="cs_play" for="cs_play1">Play</label>
    </div>

    <div class="cs_arrowprev">
        <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0">
            <span><i></i></span>
        </label>
        <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1">
            <span><i></i></span>
        </label>
        <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2">
            <span><i></i></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cs_arrownext">
        <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0">
            <span><i></i></span>
        </label>
        <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1">
            <span><i></i></span>
        </label>
        <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2">
            <span><i></i></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="cs_bullets">
        <label class="num0" for="cs_slide1_0">
            <span class="cs_point"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="num1" for="cs_slide1_1">
            <span class="cs_point"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="num2" for="cs_slide1_2">
            <span class="cs_point"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>




Check out this link for CSS carousel with Autoplay and Pause functionality - [https://projects.webdevpuneet.com/demos/set1/css-slider/index.html][1]


  [1]: https://projects.webdevpuneet.com/demos/set1/css-slider/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I know only one slider but it's a part of the website builder. 
Here you can see the link to you to demo version: https://mobirise.com/extensions/wowslider/?utm_source=extension_list&utm_medium=program&utm_campaign=win_4.8.8

If you want to use a slider, you can create it within the project and then take a code and paste to your own website.