# Can't load a simple function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/js.js"></script>
...
<input type="text" name="city" onkeyup="loadStation(this.value);"/>
...
```

and the js.js file

```
//Load Stations
function loadStation(stationCity){
  alert(stationCity);
}
```

When I try to trigger the loadStation onkeyup, nothing's happening. The path of js/js.js is ok since in the source I can load it.

What could be wrong ?

**EDIT**

I fell really stupid.... instead of href="" it should have been src="". The funiest thing is that even you guys haven't notice it :P

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your javascript source path is correct? It is using a relative path so if you are on the page `/foo/bar.php` it will try to load your script from `/foo/js/js.js` and not `/js/js.js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You could be wrong about `js/js.js`

I'd suggest using Firebug and checking that you're not getting a 404 error from your js file.

You may have wanted to use a root-relative link to the js file: `/js/js.js` so that you don't have issues with sub-directories.</del>

I've [often professed the beauty of HTML CSS & JavaScript as an MVC pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004789/pure-css-slider/7005319#7005319). So I wont go into that here, however. You should keep your HTML in `.html` files, your CSS in `.css` files, and your JavaScript in `.js` files

Using inline javascript event attributes breaks the nice MVC pattern that I often describe, so it's much better to attach the events in the script itself:

```
//wrap this in a document.ready or window.onload event callback
//-or-
//place the script *after* the input element has been added to the dom
var input;
//replace with whatever selector 
input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];works
input.onkeyup = function(){ loadStation(this.value) };

...more code...

function loadStation(val)
{
  alert(val);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRX7w/)

<del>A couple more debugging questions:

 * Are you testing a flat html & js file locally?
 * Are you uploading flat files to a server?
 * Are you able to post a url of where the content is located?</del>

You're using `href` instead of `src` on the `script` element.

Comment: With the / or not before js/js.js nothing happens. In the source code, whern I click on it, it load the js file in the source, so the path is right.

Comment: @Warface, what are you talking about "in the source code"? What editor are you using?

Comment: WIth a simple CTRL-U in Chrome you can see the source code right! and then you can click on the js/js.js path so the source code load the js.js content, and it loads so the path is correct.

Comment: I can't add the root-relative /js/js.js because the page called is not in the root but in a directory  http://localhost/example/

Comment: I can't call the .js file at all. Seriously WTF ! Seems that the serveur doesn't give a damn about that file and just ignore it.

Comment: does a simple `alert('testing')` placed within the file work?

Comment: Nope, that's what i'm saying the path is right but the javascript isn't loaded. But if I do the alert in the input, it works... So javascript is enabled on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the onkeyup like this in your js file:

```
$('body').ready(function(){
     $('#idOfInput').onkeyup(function(){
         loadStation(this.value)
     });
});
```